# What is the best way to implement precomputed data?

Tags: c#

I have a computation that calculates a resulting percentage based on certain input. But these calculations can take quite some time, which can be annoying. Since there are about 12500 possible inputs, I thought it would be a good idea to precompute all the data, and look this up during normal program execution.

My first idea was to just create a simple file which is read at program initialization and populates some arrays. Although this will work, I would like to know if there are some other options? For example that the array is populated during compile time.

BTW, I'm writing my code in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file with data is probably the easiest and most flexible way to implement it.

If you wanted it in memory without having to read it from somewhere, I would write a program to output your data in C#-like CSV format suitable for copying and pasting into an array/collection initializer, and thereby generate the source code for your precomputed data.

Comment: If you're considering a file, if your target is a windows machine, using a resource might be a better option.

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file) implements a serializer, which you can use to easily convert an object to a binary file and back.  Once you have the serializer in hand, you can just create an object that holds all your data and serialize it; when you actually run your program, just deserialize the object and use it.

This has all the benefits of saving an object to the hard drive, with an implementation that is object-agnostic (meaning you don't have to write much code for any object you want to serialize) and outputs in binary (thus saving space, if that is a concern).

Answer (score 1):

Create a program that outputs valid C# code which initializes your lookup tables.  Make this part of your build process so that it will automatically create the source file and then build the rest of your project.

Answer (score 1):

I would always start by considering if there was any way to avoid precomputing. If there's 12500 possible inputs, how many are required per user request ? Will all 12500 be needed at the same time or will they be spread out in time ? If you can get by with calculating a few at a time, I'd do that with lazy initialization. I prefer this solution simply because I'll have fewer issues with it in the long run. What do you do when the persistent format changes, or the data changes. How will you handle it when the file is missing or corrupted ? Persisting to a file does not create *less* code.

I *would* serialize such a file to a human-readable format if I had to persist a pre-loaded version. I'd probably use [xml serialization](http://www.devhood.com/Tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=236) since it's simple. But quite often there's issues of invalidation and recalculation. Do the values *never* change or only very infrequently ?

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Lew said, serialize it into a binary file.
If you need speed, go for a Dictionary. A Dictionary is indexed on it's key, and should allow rapid lookup even with large amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with mquander and Trent. Use your favorite language or script to generate the whole C# file you need to define your data (no copy-pasting, that's a manual step and error-prone). Add it as a Pre-Build event in Visual Studio. You could even detect that you have an up-to-date file and avoid regeneration for most builds.

There is definitely a way to statically generate almost any data using template metaprogramming in C++, although it can be painful. It's not worth it unless you need many sets of different data in several parts of your program. I am not familiar enough with metaprogrammation in C# to evaluate the general effort in your case. You should look into that.